# Properly bind DependencyProperty of UserControl in MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties, winui-3

I wanted to create a textbox that can search for files and also keeps track of previously used files. So I made a user control with a `DependecyProperty` that should give me the current text of the textbox and a button. But everytime I try to bind to the DependencyProperty, the property that binds to it remains empty. In short, the control looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl
    <!-- ... -->
    x:Name="PTB">

    <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="SearchBox"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=PTB, Path=FilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <Button Command="{Binding PickFileCommand}" />
</UserControl
```

I have this simple ViewModel for the user control

```cs
public string FilePath
{
     get => _filePath;
     set => SetProperty(ref _filePath, value);
}

public async Task PickFile()
{
     // ...
}
```

and this code-behind for the user control

```cs
public readonly static DependencyProperty FilePathProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("FilePath", typeof(string), typeof(PathTextBox), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextChanged)));

public string FilePath
{
     get => (string)GetValue(FilePathProperty);
     set => SetValue(FilePathProperty, value);
}

private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     if (dependencyObject is PathTextBox ptb && e.NewValue is string s)
     {
          ptb.SearchBox.Text = s;
          ptb.FilePath = s;
     }
}
```

And when I try to use it like this in my `MainPage.xaml`:

```xml
<customcontrols:PathTextBox x:Name="SearchBox"
                            KeyUp="SearchBox_KeyUp"
                            FilePath="{Binding ScriptFilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and `MainPage.xaml.cs`

```cs
private async void SearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
     {
          await ViewModel.OpenSqlFile(ViewModel.ScriptFilePath);
     }
}
```

then `ViewModel.ScriptFilePath` remains empty, even though I did bind to it. I tried a couple of different things with x:Bind etc., but I couldn't find a way to cleanly implement it in MVVM. I'm using the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm library, if that helps. Any ideas?

Comment: Does ``OnTextChanged`` get called when you change it? You can also check if ``ScripFilePath`` get updated using the partial method ``OnScriptFilePathChanged`` that the **CommunityToolkit.Mvvm** creates.

Comment: It is in fact called when I change the text. Confusingly, `ptb.FilePath` is set properly, yet its value is not propagated to the viewmodel property of my main page.

Comment: Do you see binding errors in VS?

Comment: This is not related to your question but just in case, you should create a ``RelayCommand`` instead of calling ``OpenSqlFile`` directly from code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I assume that you have the `ViewModel` in **MainPage.xaml.cs**. Then you need to add **ViewModel** to you binding code.

```xml
<customcontrols:PathTextBox
    x:Name="SearchBox"
    KeyUp="SearchBox_KeyUp"
    FilePath="{Binding ViewModel.ScriptFilePath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

or even better, use `x:Bind ViewModel.ScriptFilePath`.

Comment: Oh, I actually bind the viewmodel in MainPage.xaml.cs with `<Page.DataContext><vm:MainPageViewModel /></Page.DataContext>`. But your suggestion worked, although I don't really understand why.

Comment: Is this **WinUI 3**? I think ``Page.DataContext`` is not supported (yet?). Take look [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2687).

Comment: It is WinUI3 and I also came across this thread once. Though it states that `Window` doesn't have a DataContext anymore, `Page` still has it. That's why I'm working with pages. It still works there like in WPF/UWP.